# How to Fix unident does not match for any outer indentation level

Tags: detect, voice

i have tried to make a desktop assistant as voice recognizer and do as i say
but i get this error every time i try to run that: unindent does not match with any outer indentation level. can someone please help me! 
it is somehow copied from YouTube video

```
gtts import gTTS
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
import webbrowser
import smtplib

def talktome(audio):
    print(audio)
    tts = gTTS(text=audio, lang='eng')
    tts.save('audio.mp3')
    os.system('mpg123 audio.mp3')


def myCommand():

    r = sr.Recognizer()

 with sr.Microphone() as source:
     print('hello')
     r.pause_threshold = 1
     r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration = 1)
     audio = r.listen(source)

        try:
            command = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print('you said: ' + command + '/n')

        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            assistant(myCommand())

            return command

 def assistant(command):

     if 'open reddit python' in command:
         chrome_pathchrome_path = '/Program Files (x86)/google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'
         webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)

         if 'what\'s up' in command:
             talkToMe('i am a bit busy')
          if 'email' in command:
              talkToMe('who is the recipient?')
              recipient = myCommand()

              if 'john' in recipient:
                  talkToMe('what should i say?')
                  content - myCommand()

                  mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
                  mail.ehlo()
                  mail.starttls()
                  mail.login('username', 'password')
                  mail.sendmail('persion name', 'email address@whatever.com'. content)
                  mail.close()
                  talkToMe('email sent')
      talkToMe('i am ready for your sound')

      while true: assistant(myCommand())
```

Comment: The first bit of `myCommand` looks screwed up. `r =` should be at the same level as the `with` statement. Idk if that's what it's referring to though. What's the exact error?

Comment: hi @Carcigenicate would you mind see this error and tell what to do? thakns http://uupload.ir/files/9kwk_snapshot_۱۸-۱۲-۱۸_۱۳.۵۲.۴۹.png

Comment: wait i have removed the empty line between them and now error is : invalid syntax and the word print after that becomes red what shall i do now?